# Due date not updated in Google Tasks - Gmail UI

Tags: google-workspace, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

I created a new task in the new Gmail Tasks side panel and set the due date. I edited the due date of the task by using [Google Tasks Edit API](https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/update).

**The changes are not reflected in Tasks side panel of Gmail.**

But when I get the task using [Get Tasks List api](https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/list), the due date is correctly updated for the task.

The rest of the task details like notes, title are updated in the Gmail UI when changed using Google Tasks api.

Is this any known issue? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have an Android app that uses the Google Tasks API and I've started to get reports about this problem. Perhaps related to recent changes in Google Tasks such as adding due time as well as date to Tasks?

Comment: Somebody has raised it as a bug with Google https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129591245